# Binding Redirect Failure Visual Studio 2017 running on specific machine

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, nuget, assembly-binding-redirect

I have an issue where I am unable to run an MVC app on my local machine, as it continually fails with the following error:

[image]

The binding redirect is in place in the Web.config, but it seems as though it is being ignored:

```
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" 
      culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.1.0.0" newVersion="3.1.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
```

This works fine on other developers machines on my team, so it must be some kind of underlying issue on my machine. I am also getting the same error in another MVC app when running locally, but for a different dll. Dotnet core apps all run fine, this issue seems to only affect full fat dot net framework apps.

I've burned hours on this issue, I've deleted the working dir for the app and re cloned from git, I've uninstalled and reinstalled all the nuget packages, checked all the references and the dlls in the packages dir.

What could be causing the binding redirect to be ignored on one particular machine and not another?

Comment: See what fusion log tells, https://www.hanselman.com/blog/BackToBasicsUsingFusionLogViewerToDebugObscureLoaderErrors.aspx

Comment: reference look like incorrect at your local machine, first to check .NET version is installed correctly for your instance (check with other working instance), secondly, remove the issued reference and add that reference again (from nuget or add manually) in that .NET framework

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Lex Li's comment. FusLogger is a way to check which dlls your project is trying to load.

I have had similar issues before, there could be multiple reasons.

- It works on other devs machine. This could be because VS2015+ loads dll from a build helper instead of GAC
- Multiple versions of same dll are being referenced by one of your projects in the solution.

**Here are few things I tried to solve it**

- You can generate binding redirects again

> Check this article out:
>
> https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2014/Nov/29/Updating-Assembly-Redirects-with-NuGet
>
> There is a command to force Nuget re-write all the assembly redirects
>   in solution's config files.
>
> Just try this on Package Manager Console:
>
> PM> `Get-Project –All | Add-BindingRedirect`

- Remove that particular binding entirely and try to run it